# JPA eclipselink bypass persistence context

Tags: java, caching, jpa, eclipselink

There is a way to bypass the persistence context and use the entities only as wrapper of database tables?

I've read that I can set NONE to shared_cache_mode, but I've understand how it's works.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by bypass?  What are you trying to do exactly?

In EclipseLink you can set the "eclipselink.read-only" or "eclipselink.maintain-cache" query hints and get either read-only or detached objects back.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Query_Options

You can also disable the shared cache,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Configuring

Comment: I would to exclude Persistence Context from my queries and use EclipseLink only as a wrapper of database table. For example, when I invoke the find() function, I would to exclude the retrieved entity from Persistence Context